# Three.js How to draw slope (start point and end point with different heights)?

Tags: three.js

Currently, I can create a box or rectangle with the same heights. I am trying to create a slope (ie, starting and ending points with of box with different heights).

[rectangel with different heights using google earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c10td.jpg)

Comment: You can use [`ExtrudeGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry), with the desired shape and `bevelEnabled: false`.